# Rails 3 and Action Webservice ports

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionwebservice

I have a need to have SOAP web service on my rails app. (this is for a Quickbooks integration and QB web connector expects you to have web services on your end :(

I tried dnordberg's actionwebservice gem (gem 'actionwebservice', :git => "git://github.com/dnordberg/actionwebservice.git") which is Rails 3 port of the original data-noise/actionwebserice gem.

Since i am a relative newby to RoR (not to programming though), I am not very sure what other missing steps are. I have added the above actionwebservice gem and SOAP4R (github.com/felipec/soap4r.git)

Gemfile

```
gem 'soap4r', :git => 'git://github.com/felipec/soap4r.git'
gem 'actionwebservice', :git => 'https://github.com/dnordberg/actionwebservice.git'
```

and followed the instruction here: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ws-rubyrails/index.html.

But I just cant get the Web Service to work. I keep getting route error. (apparently rails hasn't recognised it as a WS yet, and hence looking for appropriate controller routes?).

```
No route matches [GET] "/hello_message/wsdl"
```

for http://localhost:3000/hello_message/wsdl

Can anyone provide a quick run down on the steps needed on rails 3.x ? 
Thanks!

ps: `rails g web_service` doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been working on a fork of ActionWebService and have fixed this issue for Rails 3.1.x, as well as some of the scaffolding issues. You can find my fork at http://github.com/livestation/actionwebservice

Keep an eye on it as I will be adding more fixes over the next week or so (such as the "Cannot map SOAP::Mapping::SOAPException to SOAP/OM." error you get when using the scaffold when an exception in the code is generated.)

One current caveat is that you need to add a log_error(message) function to your controller that you've assigned as an webservice controller because I haven't added this into the gem yet.

Don't forget to add the **acts_as_web_service** call into your controller to hook it all together, because that wasn't mentioned in the original docs.

[edit] forgot to mention i am using this version of SOAP4r https://github.com/spox/soap4r-spox

Look forward to your comments

Comment: Thats indeed great news, Gonna help the hapless souls like us. I had shelved this project temporarily and hope to pick it up soon. Now that you have come to the rescue, even more so:) Will mark this as answer :)

Comment: The fork linked to on longer exist at that link? Does it exist elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a new route to routes.rb?

```
match "/hello_message/wsdl" => "hello_message#wsdl"
```

Rails3 is stricter about having all routes defined

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: That resulted in a template missing exception.  Template is missing

Missing template hello_message/wsdl, application/wsdl with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "/home/thanikkal/trials/soap/app/views"

Comment: am i expected to have a view that render the wsdl as well? I would think Not ?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the following to my routes.rb:

```
  get "hello_message/wsdl"
  post "hello_message/api"
```